# Editing the graph to become with animation

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphics3d, animation, editing

In the following code:

> p1=ParametricPlot3D[{ (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u],  (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u],   Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
>
> p2=ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t](3 + Cos[t]), Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 50}]
>
> p3=ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t](2 + Cos[t]), Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (2 + Cos[t]), 
>      8+Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 50}] /. Line ->  ({CapForm[None], FaceForm[Green, White], Tube[#, .25]} &)
>
> Show[p1,p2,p3]

[image]

1. How can I animate p2 and p3 to generate simultaneously?
2. How can I download the resulting animated graph as a video?
3. How can I remove the coordinates?

Thanks!

Comment: For the last part, use `Axes ->False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{(3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
    Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Mesh -> None];

ClearAll[p2, p3]
p2[tmax_] := ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), 
    Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Thick];
p3[tmax_] := ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t] (2 + Cos[t]), 
     Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (2 + Cos[t]), 8 + Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}] /. 
   Line -> ({CapForm[None], FaceForm[Green, White], Tube[#, .25]} &);

Manipulate[Show[p1, p2[tmax], p3[tmax], PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False], {tmax, 1, 50}]
```

[image]

To export as a GIF animation:

```
frames = Table[Show[p1, p2[tmax], p3[tmax], PlotRange -> All], {tmax, 1, 50}];
Export["frames.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach the animation here? I am using an online version of mathematica and it is not very good. Thanks always!